# How to get relational data for customized AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles in ASP.NET Core 6 and EF Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I customize `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles`, and `AspNetUserRoles` to `ApplicationUser`, `ApplicationRoles`, and `ApplicationUserRoles`. I create a user Razor Pages and I write a code as follows:

```cs
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        if (_context.ApplicationUser != null)
            ApplicationUsers = await _context.ApplicationUser
                .Include(m => m.ApplicationRoles)
                .ToListAsync();
    }
```

This code gives me the following sql:

```sql
SELECT a."Id", a."AccessFailedCount", a."ConcurrencyStamp", a."Discriminator", a."Email", a."EmailConfirmed", a."LockoutEnabled", a."LockoutEnd", a."NormalizedEmail", a."NormalizedUserName", a."PasswordHash", a."PhoneNumber", a."PhoneNumberConfirmed", a."SecurityStamp", a."TwoFactorEnabled", a."UserName", t."Id", t."ConcurrencyStamp", t."Discriminator", t."Name", t."NormalizedName", t."ApplicationUserId"
FROM "AspNetUsers" AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a0."Id", a0."ConcurrencyStamp", a0."Discriminator", a0."Name", a0."NormalizedName", a0."ApplicationUserId"
    FROM "AspNetRoles" AS a0
    WHERE a0."Discriminator" = 'ApplicationRole'
) AS t ON a."Id" = t."ApplicationUserId"
WHERE a."Discriminator" = 'ApplicationUser'
ORDER BY a."Id"
```

The above sql includes a wrong column name `ApplicationUserId`. How do I correct this and set a proper relation?

My full sample project is [here](https://github.com/phasetr/ASP.NET-Core/tree/main/EFCoreQuestionSO20230315).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand to get with Include, but the [GetRoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getrolesasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method is appropriate for my temporal purpose.

**Added**:

I can find a way by using the `LINQ`'s `Join` method. The code is as follows.

```
var userInfo = await _context.ApplicationUsers
            .Join(_context.ApplicationUserRoles,
                u => u.Id,
                r => r.UserId,
                (u, ur) => new {u, ur})
            .Join(_context.ApplicationRoles,
                u => u.ur.RoleId,
                r => r.Id,
                (uur, r) => new {uur.u, r})
            .FirstAsync(m => m.u.UserName == userName);
```